# proof of homogeneous DE

Tags: differential, homogeneous-equation

I have a question about the proof of this elementary DE, the calculations are easy 
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}+a(t)y=0\rightarrow \left | y(t)\right|=\text{exp}(-\int a(t)\text{d}t+ca)\rightarrow |c\,\text{exp}(-\int a(t)\text{d}t)|=c$$
-not sure if you can multiply here by the integral and subsume it into the absolute value.
$y(t)exp(\int a(t)\text{d}t)$ is a continuous function of time 
-I'm not sure how this is assumed to be continuous in time?
If the absolute value of a function $g(t)$ is constant then $g$ must be constant, 
Proof:
1.If $g$ isn't constant there exists $t_1,t_2$ for which $g(t_1)=c$, $g(t_2)=-c$.
-if g(t)=x or d then why does g necessarily need to equal c or -c?

2.By the intermediate value theorem g must achieve all values between $-c$ and $c$ which is impossible if $|g(t)|=c$

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. The solution to the original ODE is simply $c\exp(-\int a)$, where did your absolute value come from?

Comment: The general solution is $$\begin{equation*}
\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=0\Rightarrow y(t)= y(t_{0})\exp
[-\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dsa(s)]
\end{equation*}$$

Comment: thanks I know the general solution but I'm trying to follow this proof from the Braun Differential Equations.  the absolute value is from the proof where 1/y(dy/dt)=d/dt(ln|y(t)|)

Comment: I'm not sure how you say that the function g(t) is continuous and in the proof that there exists t1, t2 for which g(t)=c or -c

Comment: I guess I should just try to move on to PDE?

Comment: is it clear to you what the steps of the proof are, but the proof has more steps than just the general solution

Comment: I also wonder how you can prove that this equation g(t) is continuous in time??